# How common are recruitment fellowships for students accepted to PhD programs?

Tags: funding

When I was applying for PhD programs, only one offered a recruitment fellowship, a small (but more than $1,000) fellowship to be disbursed in the August before the initial semester began. This turned out to be the program I joined, and as I now am beginning to look for positions, I realized this could perhaps be listed as a fellowship on my CV.

How common are recruitment fellowships for students accepted to PhD programs? Would it be appropriate to list on one's CV as "[University] Fellowship" or something to that effect?

Comment: It's pretty common in my field, amounts of $2000-5000 are generally given as fellowships for dissertation completion for top students.

Answer (score 2):

You could, without any ethical pangs, but please realize that it will not carry much weight with hiring committees. Overall, it's a feather in the cap, as they say.